# IntelliJ auto create new method that NOT exist and auto type conversion?

Tags: intellij-idea

These two quickfix features are quite simple, but in Intellj I can not find them.

For example:

```
class A {

}

A a = new A();
a.newMethod();//Eclipse can create "newMethod" function in Class A, if we put mouse at here.
```

Does there is any shortcut key ?

Comment: What do you mean by "auto type conversion"?

Comment: for example: `A a = getInstance()`; `getInstance()` return Object. It should be `A a = (A)getInstance();`

Comment: Not totally sure what you mean, but alt + enter also allows you to create local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any problems always try to put your cursor on it and hit 'alt'+'enter' first. It's standard IDEA problem solver.